# Navigation component with BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to get started with using the Android navigation component architecture along with a `BottomNavigationView`. As a simplified example, I have a `Fragment` called MainFragment with a button, which when pressed navigates to a new view with a `BottomNavigationView` which allows the user to switch between FragmentA and FragmentB. FragmentB has a button which navigates to FragmentC, and the user should be able to switch between FragmentC and FragmentA via the `BottomNavigationView`. Here is a diagram of the navigation flow:

[image: navigation flow]

My approach is to have a root nav graph to transition from MainFragment to some ContainerFragment which contains a second `NavHostFragment` and the `BottomNavigationView`. Then having a second nav graph containing Fragments A, B, and C.

main activity:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/root_nav" />
```

container fragment:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment2"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        app:navGraph="@navigation/secondary_nav" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
</LinearLayout>
```

root navigation graph:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.navtest.MainFragment"
        android:label="main_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_containerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/containerFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/containerFragment"
        android:name="com.example.navtest.ContainerFragment"
        android:label="ContainerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/container_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

Secondary navigation graph:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nested_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragment1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.example.navtest.DummyFragment"
        android:label="FragmentA"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FragmentB"
        android:name="com.example.navtest.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="FragmentB"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />
</navigation>
```

I notice in my `ContainerFragment` when I try to retreive the `NavController` to link the `BottomNavigationView` to the controller like so:

```java
NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment2);
```

that I'm only retreiving the root nav controller and not the secondary one. Does this approach even make sense? I haven't seen a particular use-case like this before.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't follow the docs that [specifically state how to show and hide a bottom nav based on what destination you are on](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake the reason is that that bottom nav is specific to that fragment so I want to contain that bottom nav in that fragment.

Comment: That's not what your diagram says at all. It shows no bottom bar when you are on your 'MainFragment' and a persistent bottom bar as you swap between Fragment A, B, and C. That's exactly the case that the docs talk about.